# ul wrapping li based on its height instead of hiding

Tags: css, listview

Let's say we have a long list:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    ...
    <li>fifty-three</li>
</ul>
```

Even if you specify the height of the ul:

```
ul {
    height: 100px;
}
```

The li elements will overflow outside of it.

Is it possible to have the elements wrap themselves on the right like a window manager's "list view" or like https://stackoverflow.com/tags (without the tables).

either through pure CSS or turning to JS.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSS3 multi-column layouts](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html) is your solution. Unfortunately, they are not widely implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks mate, it seems the browser specific markup is as close as it get for now. Let's hope people are *smart* enough to use a neat browser moz or webkite based :D

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
li { display: inline; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px; }
```

Comment: Thought of that mate, but it won't do the trick, 'cause they stack horizontally instead of vertically, that's why I gave a reference the list-view.

Comment: In SO they have implemented this in separate td in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Floating them might also help. It just depends. You'll probably want a width applied if you want them in columns

`li {float:right; width:20em;}`

don't forget to clear the float!

Comment: Almost there :) It's pretty close, though there's an issue. The list is alphabetical, and by floating them, instead of reading them by column, you're reading by row (ie, I jump columns, instead of reading vertically, then moving to the 2nd column etc).

Comment: Alas, if you want the sorting to be in vertical columns, then this is not possible in CSS (that I am aware of).

I have heard of someone writing a javascript to dynamically reorder the <li> elements, and *then* apply the float. But this does not seem like a good idea to me.

I would just use a table if you needed vertical sorting.

I heard they were going to improve the CSS spec in the future so you could do vertical column sorting of list elements - it is a pretty common way of laying out data after all.

Comment: Indeed :) n1313's answer is the closer it gets, as his links points out, we can abuse the browser specific markup (-moz and -webkit).